# Retrieve the user profile image from twitter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I am using the Twitter4J API in Java to retrieve the profile image for a Twitter user whose logged in. The command is something like :

```
twitter.getProfileImage(twitter.getScreenName(), Imagesize);
```

What is the image size? How can I display the `ProfileImage` object in a label for example?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ok, the answer is :

Assume that the Twitter object is twitter

1 - get the user from the twitter object

```
User user = twitter.showUser(twitter.getid());
```

2 - get the profile image URL

```
URL url = user.getProfileImageURL();
```

3 - create Image icon

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(url);
```

4 - set the JLabel icon to be the ImageIcon

```
Jlabel1.setIcon(img);
```

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the example code.
https://github.com/yusuke/twitter4j/blob/master/twitter4j-examples/src/main/java/twitter4j/examples/user/GetProfileImage.java

You can pass either ProfileImage.MINI, ProfileImage.NORMAL or ProfileImage.BIGGER

Comment: thanks for the answer, but how can show the image in a Jlabel for example ? can it be casted bufferd image ?

Comment: getProfileImage should not be used as the image source.