# How to get twitter profile image using Twitter4j

Tags: android, image, twitter4j, profile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieve the user profile image from twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606790/retrieve-the-user-profile-image-from-twitter)

I am making Android application that gets last tweets and pulls profile image+status text to the table. 
I tried:

```
    private void setTwitTable() {
    List<Status> statuses = null;
    try {
        statuses = getTimeLine();
    } catch (TwitterException te) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get timeline: " + te.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    TableLayout twit_tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.twitsTableLayout);

    for (Status status : statuses) {
        User user = status.getUser();

        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
        try {
            iv.setBackgroundDrawable(getDrawableFromUrl(user.getProfileImageURL(), "ProfileImage"));
            Log.d(TAG, "Image Good!");//debug
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        } 

        iv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        tr.addView(iv);
        twit_tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
}

private List<Status> getTimeLine() throws TwitterException {
    // gets Twitter instance with default credentials
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statuses = twitter.getUserTimeline(USER);
    return statuses;
}

Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(java.net.URL url, String src_name)
        throws java.net.MalformedURLException, java.io.IOException {
    return Drawable.createFromStream(
            ((java.io.InputStream) url.getContent()),
            src_name);
}
```

But I see only black background - nothing else. No images. No table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606790/retrieve-the-user-profile-image-from-twitter