# Not able to Get twitter Profile pic of users api 1.1

Tags: android, twitter

I want to get Profile picture from twitter api.

i have tried the following methods .

a)   as per this url :[Twitter4j authentication credentials are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20638190/twitter4j-authentication-credentials-are-missing) and  [Retrieve the user profile image from twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4606790/retrieve-the-user-profile-image-from-twitter)

```
//Twitter Conf.
    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY)
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET)
        .setOAuthAccessToken(ACCESS_KEY)
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(ACCESS_SECRET);

TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
User user = twitter.showUser(id of other user who using same app);
user.getOriginalProfileImageURL()
```

in this method get Exception

```
08-29 09:05:26.282: W/System.err(3823): 404:The URI requested is invalid or the resource requested, such as a user, does not exists. Also returned when the requested format is not supported by the requested method.
08-29 09:05:26.282: W/System.err(3823): message - Sorry, that page does not exist.
```

b) as per this latest url

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/profile_banner

pass screen name of user here :

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/profile_banner.json?screen_name=iRohitSachdeva
```

response: {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}.

Answer (score 0):

The correct thing to do is work out why your authentication data is going wrong.

However, the simple way to get profile images is using a service like http://avatars.io/

For example, the get my avatar, visit http://avatars.io/twitter/edent

It should return the correct URL for my Twitter account's pic.